# Replace a SQLite database at runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, sqlite

I have been developing an application that required the SQLite database file to be replaced at run time, I have code to replace db but not update the database still shows that old data. please guide me.

This is for getting the file and replace

```
ASIHTTPRequest *requestToDownloadDB = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.turfnutritiontool.com/dev.ios/services/turfnutritiontool_ver_two.db"]];
                // ======================================================================================================
                // All methods below remove old store from coordinator
                // ======================================================================================================

                NSError *error = nil;
                NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [[self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] objectAtIndex:0];
                [self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:persistentStore error:&error];
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"error removing persistent store %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }

                // then update 
                //NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
                //documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turfnutritiontool_ver_two.db"];

                NSURL *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
                NSURL *storeURL = [applicationDocumentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"turfnutritiontool_ver_two.db"];

                NSLog(@"This is store URL %@ ", storeURL);

                [requestToDownloadDB setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithString:[storeURL absoluteString]]];
                [requestToDownloadDB startSynchronous];

                // add clean store file back by adding a new persistent store with the same store URL
                if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                                                   configuration:nil 
                                                                             URL:storeURL 
                                                                         options:nil 
                                                                           error:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"failed to add db file, error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
```

Pelase take a look to my code after adding your code.

I am getting the

```
NSLog(failed to add db file, error (null), (null));
```

what should i do now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to remove the old store first:

```
// remove old store from coordinator
NSError *error = nil;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [[self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:persistentStore error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error removing persistent store %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}

// then update 
NSURL *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *storeURL = [applicationDocumentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"%xyz_ver_three.db"];

// add clean store file back by adding a new persistent store with the same store URL
if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                                   configuration:nil 
                                                             URL:storeURL 
                                                         options:nil 
                                                           error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"failed to add db file, error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

this should do the trick...

Comment: can i directly use NSPersistentStore class becuse it is giving me an error, sorry but i am new in Core data. Do i need to create an object of NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. please help me

Comment: My application right now not use core data, only SQlite use for db so do i need to use  or add core data functionality to achieve this

Comment: The erroe meassage after doing this 


ver_5.1[2038:bc03] failed to add db file, error (null), (null)

Comment: sorry, i thought you were using CoreData from the start. sometimes it's easier to setup a new xcode project and selecting coredata then than adding it later on.

Comment: well , that ok i even find hard to understand this complex process and what we are doing, haha.

But your answer is right and there is no way to swap file of sqlite db at runtime when you are not using Coredata i think?

Comment: @Retro did u find any solution for swapping the sqlite db in runtime without coredata?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to a similar problem was just to delete the file with the database:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];
```